# Completely bounded map and minimal tensor products

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

> **Theorem 3.5.2.** Let $\phi: A\rightarrow C$ and $\psi: B\rightarrow D$ ($A, B, C, D$ are C*-algebras) be c.p.(completely positive) maps. Then the algebraic tensor product map 
>   $$\phi\odot\psi: A\odot B\rightarrow C\odot D$$
>   extends to a completely positive map. (hence continuous) map on minimal tensor products. Moreover, letting $\phi \otimes \psi: A\otimes B\rightarrow C\otimes D$ we have $||\phi\otimes\psi||=||\phi||~||\psi||$.
>
> Proof. Assume $C\subset B(H)$ and $D\subset B(K)$. Let $\pi_{A}: A\rightarrow B(\bar{H})$, $\pi_{B}: B\rightarrow B(\bar{K})$ be Stinespring dilations of $\phi$ and $\psi$, respectively, and $V_{A}: H\rightarrow \bar{H}$, $V_{B}: K\rightarrow \bar{K}$ the associated bounded linear operators. Then, there is a natural *-homomorphism $\pi_{A}\otimes \pi_{B}: A\otimes B\rightarrow B(\bar{H}\otimes \bar{K})$. Hence we may define $\phi\otimes\psi: A\otimes B\rightarrow C\otimes D$ by the formula
>   $$\phi\otimes \psi(x)=(V_{A}\otimes B_{B})^{*}\pi_{A}\otimes \pi_{B}(x)(V_{A}\otimes V_{B}).$$
>   Note that $\phi\otimes \psi(a\otimes b)=\phi(a)\otimes\psi(b)$. Hence $\phi \otimes \psi$ is a c.p. which takes values in $C\otimes D$.

**I suppose there is nothing difficult in the proof of the Theorem above. But the next Remark confused me.**

**Remark 3.5.4.** It is not hard to extend the previous result to *minimal* tensor products and c.b. (completely bounded) maps.

**My question is how to extend the theorem to c.b. map?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do the same proof but using Wittstock instead of Stinespring.

Comment: But, what is Wittstock? In which text is this Theorem found?

Comment: Brown-Ozawa, page 451.

Comment: Yes, thanks, Martin.

Comment: However, the Wittstock' Theorem is for c.c. map not the c.b. map in the Remark.

Comment: But $\phi/\|\phi\|_{\rm cb}$ is completely contractive and you can apply the theorem. So Wittstock works for any completely bounded map, at the cost of allowing one of $V,W$ to not be an isometry. And you don't need isometries in the proof above.